# Laravel CORS Missing Allow Origin

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, cors

i have issue with Laravel CORS (Laravel 8.54). I have installed *fruitcake/laravel-cors* in my project, and also i have resgitered it in *kernel.php*.
The *config/cors.php* is look like this:

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

The provblem is, when i try access API from post, it is clear no problem, but when i try access API from my reactJS project that using axios (0.21) for http client, the response is always *CORS Missing Allow Origin*. I tried to access other API from my reactJS project and it is clear no problem.
Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you in adcance.

Comment: using postman , make sure all this headers is coming successfully with the response .

Comment: Your webserver may be configured differently. Show us your Apache2/Nginx configuration.